# Removing entity from Map tries to null the reference

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity `Quest` which contains many `Task`s:

```
@Entity
public class Quest {

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="quest_id")
    @MapKey(name="taskName")
    private Map<String, Task> tasks = Maps.createHash();

    @ElementCollection
    @OrderColumn
    private Set<String> completedTasks;

@Entity
public class Task implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="quest_id")
    private Quest quest;

    @Column(nullable=false,updatable=false,length=50)
    private String taskName;
```

Now when I do this:

```
// store the task as completed
quest.getCompletedTasks().add(taskName); // set
// remove the task entity
quest.getTasks().remove(taskName); // map
```

Hibernate attempts to perform the nonsensical query, and fails:

```
update Task set quest_id=null where quest_id='77149'
```

This appears to break the connection between the quest and *all* its tasks (`WHERE quest_id = ...`), which seems to me like something to do when the quest itself is removed (which it isn't). In any case, it shouldn't null anything, it should just `DELETE` the `Task` entirely.

What is wrong?

Comment: I don't see ActiveTask in your mappings

Comment: @Bozho That's what the class is really called, but I removed all "active" from the sample to make it clearer. Forgot to do the query.

Comment: You have mapped Quest to Task twice on quest_id column. On one side (e.g. Task) do a mappedBy relationship. Actually this should not work at all.

Comment: @PeterGwiazda Yes, I was looking for the functionality that `mappedBy` provides and thought I'd found it in `@JoinColumn`, but that wasn't true.

Comment: Does it work after changing to `mappedBy`?

Comment: @PeterGwiazda Yes, hence I accepted tibtof's answer which also offers that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update is not nonsensical: you remove the `task` from `quest`'s list, so hibernate deletes the connection between the `task` and the `quest`.

Update:
I just noticed that you have `@JoinColumn` and `@OneToMany` on the same field. I think you should do this instead (depending on which hibernate version you use):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="quest", orphanRemoval=true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@MapKey(name="taskName")
private Map<String, Task> tasks = Maps.createHash();
```

Comment: Actually it removes the connection between that quest and all its tasks (`WHERE quest_id = ...`), which seems to me like something to do when the quest itself is removed (which it isn't). Also, if that were the case, it shouldn't null anything, it should just remove those records.

Comment: You're right about what the update does. Please check updated answer!